# Running guile code as shell script - guile init file?

Tags: scheme, guile

I am running guile code as a shell script (starting the script file with #!/usr/bin/guile etc.) -- its working as expected, but when I do this, guile does not load my guile initialization file ~/.guile as it normally does.  Is there a different init file I need in this circumstance?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Init-File.html) (Emphasis added):

> When *run interactively*, Guile will load a local initialization file from ~/.guile.

[and also](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Command_002dline-Options.html)

> `-q`
> Do not load the initialization file, `.guile`. This option only has an effect when running interactively; *running scripts does not load the `.guile` file.* See Init File.

So what you're seeing is normal, expected behavior. But you can use the `-l filename` option to load a scheme file before the rest of the script. Something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/guile \
-l /home/XXXX/.guile -s
!#

; your script here
```

You do have to provide an absolute path to the file; things like tilde expansion aren't done when invoked using [the meta switch](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/The-Meta-Switch.html) because the shell isn't involved.